# wait-notify or sleep construct in apex missing?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I can't seem to find these types of methods in the APIs.... what i need to do is have a thread either wait until another thread is done, and then continue. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are no APIs for starting threads, there are no APIs for cross thread synchronization.

Comment: I looked around even before posting this question, and thought i was just blind.  I can't believe it...I assume it has to do with being on a multi-tenent environment..